# Visual Studio Code TypeScript

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning TypeScript and I am using Visual Studio COde as my Editor and I have created a simple hello.ts which console logs output but when I try to configure tsconfig using Command Palette and search for Configure Task Runner I cannot see options for TypeScript tsconfig or TypeScript watch?

is this some kind of error with Visual Studio code or I did something wrong? 
According to tutorial videos, these options should be available to configure and use the watch to directly compile ts to js files right?